# "Slicing" in Python Expressions documentation

Tags: python, syntax

I don't understand the following part of the Python docs:

http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#slicings

Is this referring to list slicing ( `x=[1,2,3,4]; x[0:2]` )..? Particularly the parts referring to ellipsis..

```
slice_item       ::=  expression | proper_slice | ellipsis
```

> The conversion of a slice item that is an expression is that expression. The conversion of an ellipsis slice item is the built-in Ellipsis object.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Defining simple test class that just prints what is being passed:

```
>>> class TestGetitem(object):
...   def __getitem__(self, item):
...     print type(item), item
... 
>>> t = TestGetitem()
```

Expression example:

```
>>> t[1]
<type 'int'> 1
>>> t[3-2]
<type 'int'> 1
>>> t['test']
<type 'str'> test
>>> t[t]
<class '__main__.TestGetitem'> <__main__.TestGetitem object at 0xb7e9bc4c>
```

Slice example:

```
>>> t[1:2]
<type 'slice'> slice(1, 2, None)
>>> t[1:'this':t]
<type 'slice'> slice(1, 'this', <__main__.TestGetitem object at 0xb7e9bc4c>)
```

Ellipsis example:

```
>>> t[...]
<type 'ellipsis'> Ellipsis
```

Tuple with ellipsis and slice:

```
>>> t[...,1:]
<type 'tuple'> (Ellipsis, slice(1, None, None))
```

Answer (score 34):

[Ellipsis](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/constants.html#Ellipsis) is used mainly by the [numeric python](https://numpy.org/) extension, which adds a multidimensional array type.  Since there are more than one dimensions, [slicing](https://numpy.org/) becomes more complex than just a start and stop index; it is useful to be able to slice in multiple dimensions as well. eg, given a 4x4 array, the top left area would be defined by the slice "[:2,:2]"

```
>>> a
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12],
       [13, 14, 15, 16]])

>>> a[:2,:2]  # top left
array([[1, 2],
       [5, 6]])
```

Ellipsis is used here to indicate a placeholder for the rest of the array dimensions not specified.  Think of it as indicating the full slice [:] for dimensions not specified, so
for a 3d array, `a[...,0]` is the same as `a[:,:,0]` and for 4d, `a[:,:,:,0]`.

Note that the actual Ellipsis literal (...) is not usable outside the slice syntax in python2, though there is a builtin Ellipsis object. This is what is meant by "The conversion of an ellipsis slice item is the built-in Ellipsis object." ie. "`a[...]`" is effectively sugar for "`a[Ellipsis]`".  In python3, `...` denotes Ellipsis anywhere, so you can write:

```
>>> ...
Ellipsis
```

If you're not using numpy, you can pretty much ignore all mention of Ellipsis.  None of the builtin types use it, so really all you have to care about is that lists get passed a single slice object, that contains "`start`","`stop`" and "`step`" members.  ie:

```
l[start:stop:step]   # proper_slice syntax from the docs you quote.
```

is equivalent to calling:

```
l.__getitem__(slice(start, stop, step))
```

Comment: The statement "Note that the actual Ellipsis literal (...) is not usable outside the slice syntax in python2" is not completely accurate. You can use "..." in the following way. a[3,...,5] , given that a is a class instance that defines __getitem__(self, key). The correct statement would be that Ellipsis is not usable outside index look up operator.

Comment: @abc: `a[3, ..., 5]` is technically slicing syntax.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica, I tried `a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]; print(a[3, ..., 5])` in both python2 and python3 and both times got: `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple`.

Answer (score 10):

What happens is this.  See http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#types and http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#slice

> Slice objects are used to represent
>   slices when extended slice syntax is
>   used. This is a slice using two
>   colons, or multiple slices or ellipses
>   separated by commas, e.g.,
>   a[i:j:step], a[i:j, k:l], or a[...,
>   i:j]. They are also created by the
>   built-in slice() function.
>
> Special read-only attributes: start is
>   the lower bound; stop is the upper
>   bound; step is the step value; each is
>   None if omitted. These attributes can
>   have any type.

```
x=[1,2,3,4]
x[0:2]
```

The "0:2" is transformed into a `Slice` object with start of 0, stop of 2 and a step of None.

This `Slice` object is provided to `x`'s `__getitem__` method of classes you define.

```
>>> class MyClass( object ):
    def __getitem__( self, key ):
        print type(key), key


>>> x=MyClass()
>>> x[0:2]
<type 'slice'> slice(0, 2, None)
```

For the build-in list class, however, a special `__getslice__` method must be overridden.

```
class MyList( list ):
    def __getslice__( self, i, j=None, k=None ):
        # decode various parts of the slice values
```

The ellipsis is a special "ignore this dimension" syntax provided to multi-dimensional slices.

Also see http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice for even more information.