# Problem with list slice syntax in python

Tags: python, syntax, slice

The extended indexing syntax is mentioned in python's doc.

```
slice([start], stop[, step])
```

Slice objects are also generated when extended indexing syntax is used. For example: `a[start:stop:step]` or `a[start:stop, i]`. See [`itertools.islice()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) for an alternate version that returns an iterator.

`a[start:stop:step]` works as described. But what about the second one? How is it used?

Comment: So you're asking what 'i' means in "a[start:stop, i]"?

Comment: Yes, what is "i" if a is supposed to be a sequence?

Comment: `a` is not necessarily a sequence of one of the default primitive types.

Comment: Beats the heck out of me... it raises a TypeError if I try something like foo[3:7, 2]

Comment: The documentation gives me the impression that a[start:stop, i] should work just like a[start:stop:step]. But it doesn't.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`a[start:stop,i]` calls the method `a.__getitem__((slice(start,stop,None), i))`.

This raises a `TypeError` if `a` is a list, but it is valid and useful notation if `a` is a numpy array. In fact, I believe the developers of Numpy asked the developers of Python to extend valid Python slicing notation precisely so that numpy array slicing notation could be implemented more easily.

For example,

```
import numpy as np
arr=np.arange(12).reshape(4,3)
print(arr)
# [[ 0  1  2]
#  [ 3  4  5]
#  [ 6  7  8]
#  [ 9 10 11]]
```

`1:3` selects rows 1 and 2, and the `2`  selects the third column:

```
print(arr[1:3,2])
# [5 8]
```

PS. To experiment with what slice is getting sent to `__getitem__`, you can 
play around with this toy code:

```
class Foo(list):
    def __getitem__(self,key):
        return repr(key)

foo=Foo(range(10))
print(foo[1:5,1,2])
# (slice(1, 5, None), 1, 2)
```

Comment: I see. Basically, a[start:stop, i] only works with multidimensional arrays as implemented in numpy.

Comment: @Dingle: Or, you can define your own classes with `__getitem__` and assign your own meaning and behavior!

Comment: The question is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/752602/slicing-in-python-expressions-documentation, but your example and the toy code are much easier to follow.

Answer (score 4):

The notation `[:,:]` is used to slice [multidimensional arrays](https://web.archive.org/web/20180905155049/http://structure.usc.edu:80/numarray/node26.html). Python doesn't have any multi-dimensional arrays by default, but the syntax supports it and [numpy](https://numpy.org/) for example takes advantage of this syntax.

Comment: And any other custom object which has potentially implemented multi-dimensional slicing via `__getitem__()`.